# How do I use popBackStack() to return to a previous fragment in my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to return back to a previous fragment from an activity but I cannot get the functionality to work.

Here is the relevant code from my activity class:

```
    fun previousSubCountryListButtonClicked(view: View) {

        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(R.id.navigation_scotland, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)

    }
```

and here is my fragment class:

```
package com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.ui.scotland

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.getIntent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.CountriesActivity
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.R
import com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.RegionActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_scotland.*

class ScotlandFragment : Fragment() {

    // Access a Cloud Firestore instance
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    lateinit var adapter : ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scotland, container, false)

        (requireActivity() as CountriesActivity).initializeCustomActionBar(R.drawable.scotland_flag, R.string.title_regions)

        var regions : ArrayList<String>

        val docRef = db.collection("UKSites").document("Scotland")

        val progressBar: ProgressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.regionsLoadingProgressBar)

        docRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

                progressBar?.visibility = ProgressBar.VISIBLE

                if (document != null) {

                    regions = document.get("Regions") as ArrayList<String>

                    adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, regions)

                    regionsListView.adapter = adapter

                    regionsListView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

                        val intent = Intent(activity!!, RegionActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("SUB_COUNTRY", regions[position])
                        startActivity(intent)


                    }

                    progressBar?.visibility = ProgressBar.GONE

                } else {
                    Log.d("Debug", "No such document")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("Debug", "get failed with ", exception)
            }

        return root
    }
}
```

I am struggling to understand the official documentation on Android so I would appreciate any help possible. Do I need to add a transaction in my fragment class?

Comment: did you try add ``` onBackPressed ``` in second activity to back to first activity that include your fragment ?

Comment: @noureldienmohamed I can't bring up the method ```onBackPressed(...)``` anywhere.

Comment: try this first  ```override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        val intent = Intent(this@secondActivity, firstActivity::class.java)
        this@AllTopActivity.startActivity(intent)
    }```

Answer (score 0):

I used `finish()` instead of writing code to manipulate a fragment manager.